# Missing space on /posts/<id>/timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, timeline

If you look at the timeline for a post, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/248289/timeline, you see stuff like this:

[image]

There is no space between "by" and the username "masegaloeh".

This isn't a CSS issue; the space is absent in the HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix is rolling out with build rev `2015.2.10.3061` on meta and `2015.2.10.2281` on sites.